# Присвоить значения полям класса из Dictionary в цикле..

Tags: c#, классы

Двум полям класса присваиваю значение так.

```
 static Dictionary<string, string> XmlToDict(string loadFile)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(loadFile);
        foreach (XmlNode node in document.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            string value = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
            string key = node.Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                dic.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
        return dic;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rusXml = "D:\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\obyedinenieDannix\\obyedinenieDannix\\rusXml.xml";
        string engXml = "D:\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\obyedinenieDannix\\obyedinenieDannix\\engXml.xml";
        Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = XmlToDict(rusXml);
        Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = XmlToDict(engXml);

        var vivod = dic1.Select(
    kvp => new ClassVivod()
    {
        _key = kvp.Key,
        _valueXML_1 = kvp.Value
    })
.ToArray();
```

сам класс:

```
 public class ClassVivod
{
    public string _key;
    public string _valueXML_1;
    public string _valueXML_2;

    public string Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; }
    }
    public string ValueXML_1
    {
        get { return _valueXML_1; }
        set { _valueXML_1 = value; }
    }
    public string ValueXML_2
    {
        get { return _valueXML_2; }
        set { _valueXML_2 = value; }
    }

}
```

У ClassVivod есть еще одно поле *valueXML_2. Туда надо записывать значение из dic2 при условии что* `key = dic2.Key`..если не сложно, подскажите как.

Comment: отформатируйте код. И заодно поясните, что такое **ClassVivod**, что за поле **_valueXML_2**, что такое **dic2** и как вообще ко всему этому относится тот код, что приведен у вас выше?

Comment: ClassVivod это класс с тремя полями. ключ и два значения(_key, _valueXML_1, _valueXML_2 и все типа string). dic1 и dic2 это Dictionary<string, string> считанные из разных XML. в коде выше я полям _key, _valueXML_1 класса присваиваю соответствующие значения из dic1. А в _valueXML_2 надо записывать значение из dic2 при условии что _key = dic2.Key..

Comment: @zirrama ну вы же, надеюсь, понимаете, что программировать лучше все-таки с помощью кода, а не слов, поэтому приведите лучше текст ваших классов, так будет понятнее. И не забывайте форматировать код, очень уж читать эту мешанину неудобно

Comment: Понимаю. Просто сроки поджимают вот и тороплюсь. устраиваюсь на работу дали задание такое..
добавил код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно что-то такое:

```
var vivod = dic1.Select(kvp => 
                    new ClassVivod
                      {
                          Key = kvp.Key,
                          ValueXML_1 = kvp.Value,
                          ValueXML_2 = dic2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) ? dic2[kvp.Key] : ""
                      }).ToArray();
```

Впрочем, возможно, что вы хотели чего-то другого.

Comment: То что надо)благодарю)

Comment: @zirrama немного оффтоп, но если вы устраиваетесь на работу и хотите предоставить им этот код, то я бы вам советовал его переписать во что-то более качественное - он, положа руку на сердце, просто ужасен. В нормальных конторах за такой код сильно ругают

Comment: Спасибо за совет)обычно в конце все привожу в порядок)после того как все сделаю, скину сюда для замечаний.если посмотришь буду признателен.